# Java8 streams and filters

Tags: java, java-8, guava, java-stream

I have a set multimap that stores some strings against a month(integer).

```
MonthlyCount = {1:["hello"],2:["hello","hi"]}
```

I have a map that counts the number of strings per month and adds them. I use containsKey filter to check if the key is present in the collection, and add them to the map.

```
final String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
final Map<String, Object> metaData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
private SetMultimap<Integer, String> MonthlyCount;

for (int i = 0; i <= month; i++) {
    final int count = MonthlyCount.containsKey(i + 1) ? MonthlyCount.get(i + 1).size() : 0;
    metaData.put(months[i], count);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with Java8's streams and filters ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are apparently accessing another map in the middle of the operation? What is `ticketsByMonthMap` and why do you check the presence of the key in `MonthlyCount` before getting it from `ticketsByMonthMap`?

Comment: @Holger. Thanks for pointing that out. Changed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `IntStream` to iterate over the required range and use `Collectors.toMap` to produce the required map :

```
Map<String,Integer> map =
IntStream.range(0,months.length)
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->months[i], 
                                   i->MonthlyCount.containsKey(i + 1) ? MonthlyCount.get(i + 1).size() : 0));
```

Comment: The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,Map<Object,Object>>)

Comment: @Tania I thought it might work without boxing, but you can fix it easily by boxing the Stream. See edit

Comment: Now I get Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,Integer>. I want my metadata map to remain Map<String, Object> since I add more values to it later. Is there any way this can fit?

Comment: @Tania I tried similar code and it worked. You can change the type of the Map to `Map<String,Object>` if that's what you prefer.

Comment: @Tania I just noticed your code refers to two maps - `ticketsByMonthMap` and `MonthlyCount`, but only one of them is declared. That could be your problem.

Comment: In case the two different map names are not intentional, using `Map.getOrDefault` can improve the code more than converting the loop to a stream, i.e. `MonthlyCount.getOrDefault(i+1, emptySet()).size()`…

Comment: Holger: Can you please put it as an answer?

Comment: @Eran: Thanks. Considering my map is declared elsewhere, can I just assign this to the existing map? Than declaring it in the same line? Just like map.put()?

Comment: @Tania Do you mean assign it to an existing Map variable? Yes.

Comment: Add it to the existing final map variable. i.e final Map<String,Object> metadata = new LinkedHashMap<>()?

Comment: @Tania If you are using my suggested code, a new Map will be created. You can add all the entries of that map to your existing map with `metadata.putAll(...)`

Comment: This is not preserving the order of the months. Any way to preserve order?

Comment: @Tania You can use the `toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
Supplier<M> mapSupplier)` collector and pass a `LinkedHashMap` constructor (`LinkedHashMap::new`) as `mapSupplier` in order to preserve the order.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you are doing unnecessary work. Have look at [`SetMultimap.get`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html#get(K)):

> Returns a view collection of the values associated with `key` in this multimap, if any. Note that when `containsKey(key)` is false, this returns an empty collection, not `null`.

So all you need to do in your loop, is

```
metaData.put(months[i], MonthlyCount.get(i + 1).size());
```

as it will be zero for absent keys anyway. If you have a non-guava `Map<…,Set<…>>`, you could do an equivalent operation in Java 8:

```
metaData.put(months[i], MonthlyCount.getOrDefault(i + 1, emptySet()).size());
```

where `emptySet()` is a static import of `Collections.emptySet()`.

I wouldn’t rewrite the loop to use a stream when you want to add to an existing `Map`. After all, the code is concise enough

```
for(int i=0; i<month.length; i++)
    metaData.put(months[i], MonthlyCount.get(i + 1).size());
```

and won’t become better with a stream…

Comment: Dont streams increase the performance compared to collections in this usecase?

Comment: @Tania No, streams are not any better performing than non stream code.